# html table skewed on page_Load

Tags: html, asp.net, rendering

When I launch my page, the table that is acting as the page filter is skewed...The labels on the 2nd row appear to load off the table. I'm continuing to troubleshoot this but I am at a loss to what is occuring.

Here are the screen shots:

On page_load:

After user selects a value in the Location dropdown, after a post_back occurs:

//Sorry, can't post images

Since I'm not really sure what I going on, I'm struggling with where this issue resides: There is MasterPage.

Here's the table markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="MissingDataCollection.aspx.vb" Inherits="MDC.MissingDataCollection" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.51116.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" 
        Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">        
    </asp:Panel>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

            <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" BorderStyle="none" CellPadding="0" CssClass="ReportFilterTable"
                    CellSpacing="0" Width="90%">
                    <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server" BorderStyle="none">
                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell1" BorderStyle="none" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="right" colspan="1">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSelectPractice" runat="server" Text="Label" style="text-align: right;">Select a Location:</asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell2" BorderStyle="none" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="left" colspan="4">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddnAvailablePracticeList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                                DataSourceID="sqlGetPractices" DataTextField="GroupName" 
                                DataValueField="GroupID">
                            </asp:DropDownList>                                                                  
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow2" runat="server" BorderStyle="none">
                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell5" runat="server" BorderStyle="none" height="50px" HorizontalAlign="right">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Label" style="text-align: right;">Select a Customer:</asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell6" BorderStyle="none" runat="server">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProviderList" Width="260px" Text="Please select a Customer." runat="server" CssClass="txtbox">                                
                            </asp:TextBox>
                            <div id="divDDL" runat="server">
                            </div>
                            <asp:Panel ID="PnlCust" runat="server" CssClass="PnlDesign">
                                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblProviderList" BorderStyle="none" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" onclick="readCheckBoxList();">
                                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                            </asp:Panel>                                                        
                            <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="PceSelectCustomer" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtProviderList"
                                PopupControlID="PnlCust" Position="Bottom">
                            </asp:PopupControlExtender>
                            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell ID="TableCell7" BorderStyle="none" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="right"><asp:Label ID="lblSortOrder" runat="server" Text="Label" style="text-align: right;"> Sort Order:</asp:Label>            
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell8" BorderStyle="none" CssClass="label1">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddnSortOrder" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">                                
                                </asp:DropDownList> 
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell10" BorderStyle="none" HorizontalAlign="left" ColumnSpan="1">
                             <asp:Button ID="btnRunReport" visible="true" runat="server" Text="Run Report"/>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>                    
                </asp:Table>                
            <hr />
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.Mike

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the Panel PnlCust had a defined CssClass that was setting the height of the area..?...to 150px. I've corrected that and it appears to have resolved my issue.